# transition does't work in react module css

Tags: css, reactjs, animation

I want to slide image by click next or prev button.
When I click next button, transition work well. images move from right to left.
but when I click prev button, transition doesn't work properly. end of right element go to end of left with transition animation. but all other elements doesn't move from left to right with transition animation. they move like teleporting to destination.

here is my codes. please help me.

```
banner component:

  const [index, setIndex] = useState([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
  const datas=[
    {
      id: 0,
      imgUrl: "/banner01.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 1,
      imgUrl: "/banner02.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      imgUrl: "/banner03.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      imgUrl: "/banner04.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      imgUrl: "/banner05.jpg",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      imgUrl: "/banner06.jpg",
    }
  ]

  const handleClickNext = () => {
    setIndex((prev) => {
      let temp = [...prev, prev[0]];
      temp.shift();
      return temp.slice();
    });
    console.log(index);
  };

  const handleClickPrev = () => {
    setIndex((prev)=>{
      let temp = [prev[prev.length-1], ...prev];
      temp.pop();
      return temp.slice();
    });
    console.log(index);
  };

        {index.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <div
              key={datas[item].id}
              className={styles.item}
              style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${datas[item].imgUrl})` }}
            >
            </div>
          )
        })}

banner module css:

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 0.8s;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
.item:first-child{
  transform: translateX(-250%);
}

.item:nth-child(2){
  transform: translateX(-150%);
}
.item:nth-child(3){
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
.item:nth-child(4){
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
.item:nth-child(5){
  transform: translateX(150%);
}
.item:nth-child(n+6){
  transform: translateX(250%);
}
```